# jQuery: Fire mouseup event only when input value has changed

Tags: jquery, events, bind, keyup, mouseup

I use the following lines to trigger events when an input value changes which works as intended. 
However, this also fires when I just click in the input field (without doing or changing anything there).

Is there a way that I can either prevent that it just fires on a click in the input field OR that it only fires when the value changes ? I am looking for a solution that works both on input and paste.

**My jQuery:**

```
$('input[type="text"]').bind('keyup mouseup', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var isnum = /\d/.test(val);

    if(isnum == true) {
        // do some stuff;
    } else {
        // do some other stuff;
    }
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, 
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply bind [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) and [`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) events on the element like:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('input paste', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var isnum = /\d/.test(val);

    if(isnum == true) {
        // do some stuff;
    } else {
        // do some other stuff;
    }
});
```

Please note that the `input` event is fired every time the value of the element changes. This is unlike the `change` event, which only fires when the value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like.

Also, you can use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead of `.bind()` as the `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. **As of jQuery 1.7**, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

Comment: This is perfect - thanks a lot ! This should work for what I need for text inputs. I have a similar use case with number inputs but there I also need to consider clicking on the little arrow icons that appear inside a number field. Is there a way to use this for both text and number inputs ?

Comment: Thank you also for the explanations - this helps a lot to understand. :)

Comment: Yes, you can simply use [`$( ":input" )`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector for that but it selects all input, textarea, select and button elements. You might want to give them all a class instead and use a class selector.

Comment: My pleasure. Have a great day and stay safe!